# using variables in object names

Tags: c#, .net, variables, integer, label

Okay so lets say I have a integer called `abc` and I set abc to `2.` How do I say `label2.visible = true;`?

I mean, if I set abc to 3 I want to make `label3.visible = true;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to me its easiest to put your controls into an array as follows:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[] { label0, label1, label2, label3 };
```

Toggle the visibility like this:

```
void SetVisibility(int index, bool visible)
{
    labels[index] = visible;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [`Control.FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method.

```
Label label = myForm.FindControl("label" + val) as Label;

if (label != null)
{
    // use...
}
```

Comment: that looks like what i wanted but using arrays looks shorter and easier and simplier, + point.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var theLabel = (Label) this.Controls.Find("label" + abc.toString());
theLabel.Visible = true;
```

This code is untested and off the top of my head but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

A way of doing it is to have and Array of Labels and then according to number you can do :

```
label_array[abc].visible = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, this is probably possible by reflection, but not something you would really want to do, i can't think of a valid use case.

As others have posted, use an array.

Answer (score 2):

C# Really doesn't support that type of syntax.

Put the labels into some kind of structure and use it to manipulate the labels. Here a few examples:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
int i = /* some valid index (0 based) */
labels[i].visible = true;
```

---

```
Dictionary<string, Label> labelDict = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
labelDict.add("label1", label1);
labelDict["label1"].visible = true;
```

Alternatively you could get the Labels from the parent form's list of child controls and set the visibility that way.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple examples

```
 if(abc == 2)
     {
          label2.visible = true;
          label3.visible = false;
      }
   else if(abc ==3)
      {
         label3.visible = true;
         label2.visiable = false;       
      }

 or use a switch statement

    switch(abc)
    {
       case 2:
             label2.visible = true;
             break;
       case 3:
             label3.visible = true;
             break;

    }
```

Comment: yea but this is well... not good really this will work for 2 or 3 label but i dont really want to write that much code when i have more label(which i do).

Comment: Yes it is not the best approach but i did not know your level of programming, so i was trying to help with an idea :)... go for the array examples :D